# How to open a JFrame in different package from another JFrame which is in other differernt package but in the same project

Tags: java, swing, package, jframe

I am doing a demo project, where this time I have created different packages and put some different `JFrames` in those `packages`.

I want it to open when I call the `JFrame` of a `different package` from the JFrame of another `package`.

But, I have **three packages**, one of which is `package com.mkw.adminpanel;` which contain a `JFrame` named **Admin** And by clicking the button here I want `package com.mkw.loginpanel;` To open the `JFrame` named **Start** inside. But it is not opening.And `package com.mkw.studentpanel;` The frame named **Start** inside this package is opening.

the package named `package com.mkw.adminpanel;` code of JButton actionperformed is given below:

```
package com.mkw.adminpanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import com.mkw.studentpanel.Start;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Admin extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Admin frame = new Admin();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public Admin() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dispose();
            Start s = new Start();
            s.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(175, 182, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
   }
}
```

Comment: Relevant information: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)

Comment: In general is not a good idea to have classes with same name in the same project, even in different packages, nevertheless you can distinguish them by using the fully qualified name, so replace `new Start(...);`, with `com.mkw.loginpanel.Start(...);`

Comment: @maloomeister I know about card layout. I always use this layout. But this time I want to do with different packages.Because in Eclipse the codes are so long if i use card layout and hard to find specific line.

Comment: 1) What's a `Start`? For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).3) Also, agree with @maloomeister. `JDialog`s!

Comment: But using a `CardLayout` does not stop you from structuring your code? You can e.g. instead of subclassing `JFrame`, subclass `JPanel` and add these to your `CardLayout`?

Comment: @Rocco Thanks It works! Actually I have never used different packages in the same project before. So, really I have no Idea about it. I Always use card layout for multiple frames. that's why for the first time I find the problem :(

Comment: *"in Eclipse the codes are so long if i use card layout"* They don't **have** to be long! You might code each panel or view as a single class, then reference them from the code that uses the card layout.

Comment: @maloomeister card layout is really useful for me.But, I am trying to do something different this time.That's why I avoid card layout this time. otherwise in my many projects i use card layout to make my projects.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I mean that also. sorry for my typing or grammatical mistake